# Node js mongoose MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make many to many relation between two collection categories and products and i am trying to view it on a table using populate() but it shows error 'MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Category"'.

Category.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      catname: String,
      product: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Product"
        }
      ]
    });


  module.exports = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
```

Product.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    quantity: String,
    price: String,
    categories: [ 
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category"
      }
    ]
  });


module.exports = mongoose.model('product', contactSchema);
```

home.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Club = require('../models/Club');
const Category = require('../models/Category');



// ROUTE FOR READ
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    let all_categories = [];
    Category.find((err, docs) => {
        all_categories = docs;
    });
    Club.find({}).populate('categories').exec((err, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log(docs);
        res.render('home', {
            products: docs,
            categories: all_categories
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
```

you wrote category in lower case. So your ref should be 'category' or the model be initialized with

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```